# How can I save staff_name column as others in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I am making ledger app to kill the paper work.

but making simple CRUD, there was a problem.

Other columns are OK, but one column cannot be saved.

Would you take a look at this?

I am just making add, edit, delete, and view ctp files
as bake command generated .

And the Controller also made by bake command.

I just changed POST method to GET method.

### tried

- re-making table columns, make sure I am using correct name.
- make sure I am using correct cake grammar.
- add accessible in Entity

```
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true
    ];
```

#### add.ctp

```php
<div class="ledgers form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($ledger) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Ledger') ?></legend>
        <?php
            $men = [
                'Fukuda','Hayasi','Seki','Kubo'
            ];
            $work_category = [
                'preview','build','repair','etc'
            ];

            echo $this->Form->control('customer_name');
            echo $this->Form->control('customer_adress');
            echo $this->Form->control('customer_tel1');
            echo $this->Form->control('customer_tel2');

            // need arr, $members = [hukuda, hayasi,ryo]
            echo $this->Form->control('staff_name', 
                ['options' => $men,
            ]);
            echo $this->Form->control('work_category',
                ['options' => $work_category,
            ]);
            echo $this->Form->control('content');
            echo $this->Form->control('reserved');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

I want to make select form to restrict categories.

#### LedgersController.php

```php
    public function edit($id = null) {
        // return the GET data (in url)
        $ledger = $this->Ledgers->get($id);

        // this is POST only -------------
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {

            $ledger = $this->Ledgers->patchEntity(
                $ledger, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Ledgers->save($ledger)) {
                $this->Flash->success(
                    __('The ledger has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(
                    ['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(
                __('The ledger could not be saved.'));
        }
        // POST
        $this->set(compact('ledger'));
    }
```

#### DB

```
MariaDB [fesa]> desc ledgers;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| customer_name   | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| customer_adress | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| customer_tel1   | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| customer_tel2   | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| work_category   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content         | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created         | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reserved        | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified        | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| staff_name      | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

all code is here

https://github.com/kaede0902/cake3/tree/master/ledger/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this select option may help.

**add.ctp**

```
<div class="ledgers form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
<?= $this->Form->create($ledger) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Ledger') ?></legend>
    <?php

        echo $this->Form->control('customer_name');
        echo $this->Form->control('customer_adress');
        echo $this->Form->control('customer_tel1');
        echo $this->Form->control('customer_tel2');
        echo $this->Form->control('staff_name', [
            'type' => 'select',
            'placeholder' => __('staff_name'),
            'label' => __('staff_name'),
            'empty' => __('(Choose Type)'),
            'value' => $ledger->staff_name,
            'options' => [
                        ['value' => 'Fukuda', 'text' => __('Fukuda')],
                        ['value' => 'Hayasi', 'text' => __('Hayasi')],
                        ['value' => 'Seki', 'text' => __('Kubo')],
                        ['value' => 'Kubo', 'text' => __('Kubo')]
                    ]
        ]);

        echo $this->Form->control('work_category ', [
            'type' => 'select',
            'placeholder' => __('work_category '),
            'label' => __('work_category'),
            'empty' => __('(Choose Type)'),
            'value' => $ledger->work_category ,
            'options' => [
                        ['value' => 'preview', 'text' => __('preview')],
                        ['value' => 'build', 'text' => __('build')],
                        ['value' => 'repair', 'text' => __('repair')],
                        ['value' => 'etc', 'text' => __('etc')]
                    ]
        ]);
        echo $this->Form->control('content');
        echo $this->Form->control('reserved');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

this style also help you for easy editing too.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's so ... beautiful.

Comment: With your code, (type, placeholder, label, and empty ) will be included to select choices, so I used empty and option only.

Answer (score 0):

Table name was messed up.
I was confused because column `staff_id` cannot use because of the cake php condition,
So I made new column `worker` and replacing this, but it was complicated. 
It worked well when I integrate the code with `staff_id`

I was also confused by `<th> and <td>`

```
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->
                    sort('id') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->
                    sort('customer_name') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->
                    sort('customer_tel1') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->
                    sort('customer_tel2') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->
                    sort('staff_name') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->
                    sort('work_category') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->
                     sort('created') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->
                    sort('reserved') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->
                    sort('modified') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="actions">
                    <?= __('Actions') ?></th>
```

```
            <?php foreach ($ledgers as $ledger): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $this->Number->format($ledger->id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($ledger->customer_name) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($ledger->customer_tel1) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($ledger->customer_tel2) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($ledger->staff_name) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($ledger->work_category) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($ledger->created) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($ledger->reserved) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($ledger->modified) ?></td>
```

Comment: What is your confusion about `<th>` and `<td>`?

Comment: I thought th was data and td was title.

Comment: They're not named as intuitively as some other table tags, like `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>`, so they're easy to mix up. `<th>` actually stands for "table header" and `<td>` stands for "table data".